# How dose a SSR(socks5) client change TLS & http packets without administrator permission?

Tags: python-3.x, http, proxy, tls1.2, socks

I am working on an idea that I may forcefully make every TCP packet of applications on my computer 'proxied' without using TUN or TAP. I tried to realize this by sniffing and using pydivert module to change the packets.
However, I can't find any infomation about how to change a normal TLS or http packet to the one that will be sent to the proxy and encrypted.
And, I feel puzzled about how an ordinary SSR client changes something and thus 'proxys' every http and TLS requests from browsers? Can I detect the change? Can I find what have been changed through python? or os commands?
I believe the change can be detected as settings of Firefox offers an option that 'Firefox should follow the proxy setting of the system'.And when this option is enabled, Firefox successfully connects to the proxy sever.

This is not a usual question on debugging, so the 'what did you tried' part is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found the solution:

```py
from urllib import request
print(request.getproxies())
```